# Is it possible to move to a point without drawing a line using turtle python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.setx(0)
t.sety(300)
turtle.clear() #tried turtle.reset() too
for i in range(3):
   t.fd(100)
   t.right(90)
t.goto(0,300)
turtle.done()
```

So I've been wondering if it was possible to move to a point or set of axes without drawing a line using turtle. By default, it is set to (0,0), but I wish to move up the screen, say point (0,300), but before moving to that point, it draws an unwanted line. I tried to set the coordinates, then used the clear() and reset() function but none seemed to produce the desired output. Any hints please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `penup()`. Essentially, it lifts up the turtle's pen.

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
t.goto(0, 300)
#Now you can set pen down if you wish with turtle.pendown()
```

Comment: Thanks Sid, I appreciate. The above code works, but creates another turtle that moves up to (0,300) without drawing a line, while the other turtle is at (0,0) . If I set pen down and perform an action say move forward, the turtle at (0,300) is stationary, while that at (0,0) does the action instead. What could be the issue please?

Comment: @manuel sounds like you're not using the same turtle object. Nothing else can be said without analyzing the code

Answer (score 0):

There's only one small bug in your code: simply replace the `turtle.clear()` with `t.clear()` to clear the lines made by `t` specifically:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.setx(0)
t.sety(300)
t.clear()
for i in range(3):
   t.fd(100)
   t.right(90)
t.goto(0,300)
turtle.done()
```

Also, you can use the `t.penup()` method to "lift" the pen whenever necessary, and `t.pendown()` to lower it back onto the canvas whenever necessary.

*P.S. `t.penup()` can also be `t.pu()`, and `t.pendown()` can be `t.pd()`!*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `teleport()` method to do that. This will move the turtle without drawing a line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).